# Too many redirects , try to clear your cookies error showing in code igniter

Tags: codeigniter

This is my user controller file.
When it redirect to the destination page, it is showing an error that:

> too many redirects, try to clear your cookies . ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Here is my controller code.

```
public function send_quick_register_mail(){

    if ($this->checkLogin('U') != ''){

        redirect(base_url());

    }else {
         $quick_user_name = $this->session->userdata('quick_user_name');

        if ($quick_user_name == ''){
            redirect(base_url());

        }else {
            $condition = array('user_name'=>$quick_user_name);
            $userDetails = $this->user_model->get_all_details(USERS,$condition);

                            if ($userDetails->num_rows() == 1){
                                $this->session->set_userdata('regMessage','regSuccess');

                $this->send_confirm_mail($userDetails);
                $this->login_after_signup($userDetails);
                $this->session->set_userdata('quick_user_name','');


                                  $login_redirect = base_url().'browse';

                            }else {

                         $login_redirect = base_url().'browse';
            }
            redirect($login_redirect);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `base_url()`?

Comment: Base url is http://exchangehub.net/

Comment: Your best bet here is to echo out a reference before each redirect and then die()/exit your code. That way you'll see which redirect is triggering your problem. It may well be that a number of them are redirecting but if they are - then you want to know why they are.